# Creating 2D array of strings, values will be entered by user in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm trying to create a 2D array of strings which will include values entered by user.

I'm getting some errors in Visual Studio 2013 that say something along the lines of:

```
no suitable conversion function found from 'std::string' to 'const char*' exists.
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {        
    string stringOne, stringTwo, stringThree, stringFour, stringFive;
    const char *myStrings[][5] = { stringOne,
                                   stringTwo,
                                   stringThree,
                                   stringFour,
                                   stringFive };
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply [`std::array<string,5> myStrings = { ... };`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: @onderbakirtas One more what are you trying to create?

Comment: You should declare it some thing like char myStrings[size1][size2]; Refer to this http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Arrays

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'm trying to create a data table with 2D arrays. That's why I have a undefined first array.

Comment: @onderbakirtas See my answer. It seems it is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should use vectors and not arrays in C++. You can initialize a nested vector like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v = {
    { stringOne, stringTwo, stringThree, stringFour, stringFive }
};
```

If you're getting input from the user, you don't have to use five different string variables. Instead, you can use push_back to increase the size of your vector. Something like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v(5);
std::size_t row = 0;
std::size_t column = 0;
std::string input;
while (std::cin >> input)
{
      if (row++ < 5)
           v[column].push_back(input);
      else
      {
           row = 0;
           column++;
      }
}
```

Comment: The code has undefined behaviour as you are using references to elements in `v` that don't exist.

Comment: @snps Ok no longer an issue.

Answer (score -1):

It is difficult to understand what you want. Maybe you mean the following:)

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string>

//...


std::vector<std::array<std::string, 5>> myStrings;
```

Here is an example of this approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::array<std::string, 5>> myStrings;

    myStrings.push_back( { "FirstString", "SecondString", "ThirdString", 
                           "FourthString", "FifthString" } );

    std::string firstString( "FirstString" );
    std::string secondString( "SecondString" );
    std::string thirdString( "ThirdString" );
    std::string fourthString( "FourthString" );
    std::string fifthString( "FifthString"  );

    myStrings.push_back( { firstString, secondString, thirdString, 
                           fourthString, fifthString } );

    for ( const auto &a : myStrings )
    {
        for ( const auto &s : a ) std::cout << s << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
FirstString SecondString ThirdString FourthString FifthString 
FirstString SecondString ThirdString FourthString FifthString
```

So you will get a table of five columns of objects of type `std::string`

Comment: Wasn't the _question_ involving user input?